# Shared Element Transition - Animate a layer-list background as one solid background

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

Im struggling to create a Shared Element Transition in android between two activities that scales an layer-list background as if it was one solid background.

This is how it currently looks like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFbyf8-sPdw

The background is being scaled as two different objects.

Background xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="80dp"
          android:id="@+id/card_background_top">

        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >

            <gradient
                android:type="linear"
                android:startColor="@color/card_ocean_blue_start"
                android:endColor="@color/card_ocean_blue_end"
                android:angle="45" />

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
        </shape>


    </item>

    <item android:top="120dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white"
                android:height="100dp"/>

            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Set the animation like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.card_shared_elemement_transition);
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
}
```

And the transition looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="together"
    android:duration="400">
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeImageTransform/>
    <fade
        android:fadingMode="fade_in"
        android:startDelay="200">
    </fade>
</transitionSet>
```

Comment: A workaround for this problem was to change the `<item android:bottom="80dp"` to `<item android:bottom="5dp"` then it does not show anymore.